# Bulk content load and Page Creation in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have a process where i am getting xml resultset , from which i can process the data and programmatically create pages in Sitecore. This is simple if we have to few pages that even once .
Now my problem is that i have to create minimum 50k pages in Sitecore twice a day from xml.So to load that much data in sitecore once is really slow process.
Is there is a optimum way to create these pages in Sitecore .

I am using Sitecore 7.

process for page creation

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item.count; i++)
    {
        Item newCityItem = parentCityItem.Add("Page_" + i, template1);
        newCityItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
        try
        {
            newCityItem.Fields["html"].Value = mPages[i].ToString();
            newCityItem.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {     
            // The update failed, write a message to the log    
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Could not update item " + newCityItem.Paths.FullPath + ": " + ex.Message, this);
            // Cancel the edit (not really needed, as Sitecore automatically aborts     // the transaction on exceptions, but it wont hurt your code)    
            newCityItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help ...

Comment: Are you loading 50k worth of new pages everyday, or are some of them new and updates to some existing ones? Do you have any timestamps in your xml to be able to check when the content was last updated?

Comment: These pages will be new everyday and then i am deleting the previous day pages , as i update the new pages.

Comment: @jammykam i can manage the process of taking xml to db . Once i have Data in DB , then what will be best practice to generate this amount of pages daily.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your loop in a BulkUpdateContext which disables events, indexes, etc

```
using(new BulkUpdateContext())
{
   // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's another way to create Sitecore Items.

What I suggest you, to disable indexing on master database, because it will slow a little bit when new items are created. If you need to index after creating your items you can enable again the indexes and start reindexing.

Answer (score 1):

If these items are being replaced twice a day in Sitecore, I assume that they're not being edited and you're using Sitecore for the presentation layer.

If so, you could map your xml as a Sitecore DataProvider. This way, the xml is used as the source of the items - although they can still be read in Sitecore, and the Sitecore presentation layer sees them as regular sitecore items.

There's a blog post explaining it at http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2013/03/17/an-introduction-to-sitecore-data-providers/, as well as some documentation in the SDN.

**Edit (thanks to jammykam)**

I wouldn't map direct to an xml file - maybe put that into a db and then map *that* into sitecore.

Comment: Not sure I would want to read 50k pages worth of data from XML files. I agree the data provider is one way to go, but I would prob run an ETL process to dump the data into an SQL database and have the dataprovider retrieve from that. Good option though.

Comment: I wouldn't either, but wanted to put it forward as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Everytime when you save an item, the statistics were updated (like modified user, modified date etc.) and all the events were fired (item saved, index building, etc). You can disable both of these:

```
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item["Title"] = "My new title";
item.Editing.EndEdit(false, true);
```

Depending on your requirements you may need to rebuild the index at the end of your import.